# In a Chrome extension, is it possible to reliably move an extension's popup window off-screen?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When a Chrome extension's keyboard shortcut is pressed, I create a popup window using `chrome.windows.create({ type: "popup", ... })`.  In order to keep the extension as responsive as possible, I want to "hide" the window by moving it off-screen.  That way, the next time the extension's keyboard shortcut is invoked, I can simply move the window on-screen to "show" it.  This avoids the OS's new window animation, painting the browser chrome, loading the page, etc.

I use `chrome.windows.update(<windowId>, { left: 10000, top: 10000 })` to move the window to a pixel position that's off-screen, and later move it on-screen to show it.

On Windows 10, this works perfectly when the UI scaling in the Display settings is set to 100%.  Unfortunately, if the UI is scaled to say, 150%, moving the window off-screen doesn't work (though, occasionally, it does).  If I move the window to `{ left: 10000, top: 10000 }`, the window ends up in the bottom-right corner of the screen.  If I move it to `{ left: -10000, top: -10000 }`, it ends up in the top-left.

On macOS 10.15, the window gets mostly moved off-screen, but with a sliver left visible.  So it looks like I'm running into some OS-specific behavior/bugs.

Is there any way to reliably move/hide a popup window off-screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in extension API for that.

Workaround 1: reposition the auxiliary window under the main one.

Workaround 2: minimize the auxiliary window by [setting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) its `state` to `'minimized'`.

Workaround 3: use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to run a separate utility (you can write it in any language e.g. node.js that runs on all platforms) that will use the low-level OS methods to manipulate window visibility directly.

Workaround 4: insert the UI inside the page as DOM + ShadowDOM.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm leaning towards #1, as moving the window clearly isn't going to work on Mac, though if you're a window-enthusiast like me, there's not a "main" window to hide behind. I started out with #2, but the (un)minimize animation on Windows is a bit slow, and on Mac it's unbearable. #3 using node is interesting, but wouldn't that require bundling a full node installation with the extension? Seems very heavy. I'm not sure I understand #4, but if you mean rendering the UI within the current page, I don't want to have to ask for that permission.

Comment: The other workaround I've explored is creating the UI as a tab in the bottom-most window, and then creating a popup with that tab to show it, and moving it back to the window to hide it. This avoids a reload, but still shows an open and close window animation, which on Windows paints the screen black before closing, though on Mac it's quite fast and smooth. The other disadvantage is you can see the tabs shift as the tab is removed/added, if the window is visible. The advantage over #1 is the popup window isn't left in the alt-tab stack.

Comment: Depending on how your extension is invoked #4 might require only the `activeTab` permission. As for node.js, it can be downloaded from its server.